# On an cellEditable material-table, how to restrict the user from entering negative number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

i am using material table cell editable in my project. I want to restrict users from entering negative no in the field. also, throw error validation. How to achieve that??

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h1f8d?file=/demo.js:609-979

```
 <MaterialTable
      title="Cell Editable Preview"
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      cellEditable={{
        onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("newValue: " + newValue);
            setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
          });
        }
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Material-table supports [validation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/validation) through the columns. You have to add the validate key in the columns and then validate based on your requirement. For example:

```
columns={[
    {
          title: 'Name', field: 'name',  validate: rowData => rowData.name === '' ? 'Name cannot be empty' : ''
    },     
]}
```

The above code will through an error if the name is empty. You can do the same for the required cells in your case.
[image]

Comment: Hi. I see it is not working in code... can you add that in codesanbox and check : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-h1f8d?file=/demo.js:609-979

Comment: `{
      title: "Surname",
      field: "surname",
      initialEditValue: "initial edit value",
      validate: rowData => rowData.surname === '' ? 'Surname cannot be empty' : ''
    },`

Comment: yes i tried... but i am using cellEditable and it is not working

Comment: I saw that but didint helped